# I am trying to set info from the array into the variable using second variable to retrive info

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to set info from the array using second variable to recieve data from array

I can echo this (like this):

```
call echo %%line[%i%]%%
```

But cant use it to set variable (I try this):

```
set content=%%line[%i%]%%
```

Comment: [Arrays, linked lists and other data structures in cmd.exe (batch) script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the same `call` trick with the `set` command?

```
set i=2
set line[2]=hello
call echo %%line[%i%]%%
call set content=%%line[%i%]%%
echo %content%
```

Output:

```
> set i=2

> set line[2]=hello

> call echo %line[2]%
hello

> call set content=%line[2]%

> echo hello
hello
```